# Getting Error "C2059 syntax error: 'constant'" and Im unable to figure out what the problem is

Tags: pong

I'm a beginner trying to make Pong using SFML and Visual Studio 2022. I'm unsure of what this error means and when I look it up the answers are unhelpful to me because I am either too new to programming to understand what I need to do or it is not an answer to my problem in general. I wish I could post all the code as text here but it'd simply be too much to post.
So heres a link to download: https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Erahb2yzsql58NW07JaA89eMV9qTlHVI?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your problem isn't the code, but the build tools you're using. If you navigate to your log file 'pong/pong/x64/debug/pong.log' you will see the following issue:[image: LogFile]

Follow those steps and i'm sure you will get there.